# Infinite scroll feature in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using JQM and phongap do make an android application. I am trying to add an infinite scroll feature to the app but it is not working in the app. It is working perfectly in Firefox and chrome. Here is my js code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()
                                   && document.location.hash == "#trending") {
        $.getJSON("http://www.xxx.com/json.php", function(json) { //append it
            to html 
        });     
    } 
});
```

How can I made the above code work with android apps? what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using JQM, an alternative method that will work for android and iOS would be to use the [jquery-mobile-iscrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) plugin which provides the kind of pull-to-update infinite scroll functionality you're looking for as well as a range of other mobile-centric scrolling features such as momentum.